# Why are the icons of the imported icon library not displayed in VUE?

Tags: css, vue.js, fonts, icons

I am developing my first application at Vue and I must say that I am having a hard time finding practical examples and complete information for all the problems I am encountering.
Right now I'm trying to use an icon font that I've created with iconomoon.  I've imported it into my project and I've declared it as a font-face in my style, importing the declaration of the icon I want to test with into the same style.
At first I had a webpack configuration error that I have already corrected, but when I declare my icon in my html template only a box with a border appears but the icon is not shown

Here is my template

```
               <header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light header">
                  <img class="logo" src="../../assets/logo.png">
                  <i class="icon-ic-fluent-home-24-regular"></i>
```

and here my css

```
<style>

 @font-face {
    font-family: "icomoon";
    src: url(../../icons/icomoon.ttf) format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }

.icon-ic-fluent-home-24-regular:before {
  content: "\e908";
}
[![project strucutre][1]][1]

</style>
```

Can someone tell me what my mistake is?
Thank you very much for your time and help in advance

[![the square in the image corresponds to what it shows instead of the][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/btYW0.png

Comment: Does the :before element actually have that font set?

Comment: @dantheman93 is as stated in the example html of the source

Comment: @dantheman93 but if I include it in the html statement it doesn't even show the borders

Comment: I don't know what that means, but if you look here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/ and inspect the icons, you'll see that the icon element has a font-family set saying to use the icon font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the icon to use the font you created:

```
<i class="icon icon-ic-fluent-home-24-regular"></i>


<style>

 @font-face {
    font-family: "icomoon";
    src: url(../../icons/icomoon.ttf) format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }

.icon {
    font-family: "icomoon"
} 

.icon-ic-fluent-home-24-regular:before {
  content: "\e908";
}


</style>
```